# Unicode/Mini Letters above other Character?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have searched by and large and can't find out what this is called, it's some type of Unicode character set but I haven't the slightest clue.

Hopefully this appears:

what is this called? Unicode something?

> tͭeͤxͯtͭ oͦn tͭoͦp oͦf hͪeͤrͬeͤ

If it doesn't appear here is an image:

[image]

I am not sure how to get `iconv` to identify this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're part of [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), specifically U+0363 through U+036F.

```
$ charinfo 'tͭeͤxͯtͭ oͦn tͭoͦp oͦf hͪeͤrͬeͤ'
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Ll]
U+036D COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Mn]
U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Ll]
U+0364 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Mn]
U+0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X [Ll]
U+036F COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER X [Mn]
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Ll]
U+036D COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Mn]
U+0020 SPACE [Zs]
U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Ll]
U+0366 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Mn]
U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N [Ll]
U+0020 SPACE [Zs]
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Ll]
U+036D COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER T [Mn]
U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Ll]
U+0366 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Mn]
U+0070 LATIN SMALL LETTER P [Ll]
U+0020 SPACE [Zs]
U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Ll]
U+0366 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Mn]
U+0066 LATIN SMALL LETTER F [Ll]
U+0020 SPACE [Zs]
U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H [Ll]
U+036A COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER H [Mn]
U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Ll]
U+0364 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Mn]
U+0072 LATIN SMALL LETTER R [Ll]
U+036C COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER R [Mn]
U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Ll]
U+0364 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER E [Mn]
```

Comment: Is `charinfo` an on-the-shelf tool or did you make it yourself?

Comment: Very nice, sheesh! I couldnt find it for the life of me thank you!

Comment: @daxim: I wrote it, others copied it.